Is there a comprehensive grammar of British English from the early twentieth century that you recommend?
I am a native English speaker and I would like to read an old-fashioned grammar of British English: one that is prescriptive, one that predates generative linguistics
I have been enjoying "The King's English" by H W Fowler and F G Fowler, and I would like to read a grammar book that is written in a similar style - so I thought that a grammar of British English from the early twentieth century would be a good fit, but I'm happy for it to be older than that
I am looking for a comprehensive grammar book, which I think neither "The King's English" nor Fowler's "Modern English usage" is
By comprehensive I mean that it starts with the basics and then systematically covers a good deal of ground
I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions
